# ClassName with apostrophe gives unrecogonized error in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add active to a class with id name.It works fine if there is no apostrophe.But throws syntax error,uncaught expression when the name has apostrophe

```
var name="sam's"
$('#'+name).addClass('active');
```

Any workaround

Comment: `var name="sam\\'s"`

Comment: Are you really allowed single quote in ID name? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters suggests not... "In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);"  I'd seriously recommend against this non-standard approach

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `$('[id="' + name + '"]')`

Comment: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - `To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.`

Comment: @Adam This is HTML though, not CSS. In HTML5, the `id` attribute may contain just about anything other than a space. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: I know, but creating an ID which cannot be referenced by CSS, is that a good idea?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea, there isn't really any benefit in using apostrophes, just trouble...

Comment: It is not a good practice to contain apostrophe in a variable value. 
So change the value of var name.